# Passing an entity from one method to another method located in different classes

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have an object, there are two values ​​in the object, username and email, and I have a controller class, the controller shows user.html, which has two inputs and one button, when the button is clicked, the data in the inputs is written to the data, the program works, but how can i move data writing function to UserService?

I tried to do this, but the method that I implement in UserService to implement database operation requires User data type, but the method in usersShow in UserController has String data type.

Example:

```
public User usersShow(User user) {
//Implementation of the database
}
```

The following is an example of existing code that is currently in my program.

MainController.class:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping
public class MainController {

private final UserRepository userRepository;

@Autowired
public MainController(UserRepository userRepository) {
this.userRepository = userRepository;
}

@GetMapping(path = "/users")
public String usersPage(Model model) {
model.addAttribute("user", new User());
return "user";
    
}

@PostMapping(path = "/users")
public String usersShow(@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {
System.out.println(userRepository.findAll());
userRepository.save(user);
return "redirect:/user";
}

@Controller
@RequestMapping
public class MainController {

private final UserRepository userRepository;

@Autowired
public MainController(UserRepository userRepository) {
this.userRepository = userRepository;
}

@GetMapping(path = "/users")
public String usersPage(Model model) {
model.addAttribute("user", new User());
return "user";
    
}

@PostMapping(path = "/users")
public String usersShow(@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {
System.out.println(userRepository.findAll());
userRepository.save(user);
return "redirect:/user";
}

}
```

UserService.class (Here I want to transfer work with the database, but I don’t know how):

```
@Service
public class UserService {

private final UserRepository userRepository;

@Autowired
public UserService(UserRepository userRepository) {
this.userRepository = userRepository;
}
```

Comment: Can you specify what exactly would you like to move into `UserService`?

Comment: I didn’t put it correctly, I want to move the implementation of working with the database to UserService, I hope it’s clearer, I’m sorry, I don’t know English well

Comment: Do you mean the calls for `findAll` and `save`?

Comment: Yes, I mean it.

Comment: I see and I understand your intent. Basically you want to separate business logic affecting the database from your controller, which is a good approach to coding. However, I want to add, it is perfectly normal to trigger business logic from your controller. Calling `save` and `findAll` by itself does not violate this principle of separation, because you will need somehow to trigger them. Yet, if you really really want to move these function calls into the business layer, you can implement a `getAll` method that will call `findAll` and return its result. The benefit of such a change would be

Comment: that if, over time your `findAll` becomes nontrivial, then it will evolve into a more complicated code inside the business layer rather than at the controller. Similarly, you could implement a `store` inside the business layer that will call the `save`. Yet, I would not do it right now if I were you, because, when the code becomes nontrivial, you will have a better understanding of how it changed and you may have a better response at that point than if you do it now preemptively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't do what I wanted to do, but I did better and I'm quite happy with it.

I remade the UserService into an interface and created a UserServiceImpl created the following methods, here is the code:

UserService.interface:

```
package authentication.service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import authentication.entity.User;

public interface UserService {

User addUser(User user);

}
```

UserServiceImpl.class:

```
package authentication.service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import authentication.entity.User;
import authentication.repository.UserRepository;

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

private final UserRepository userRepository;

@Autowired
public UserServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository) {
this.userRepository = userRepository;
}

@Override
public User addUser(User user) {
User saveUser = userRepository.saveAndFlush(user);
    
return saveUser;
}

}
```

MainController.class:

```
package authentication.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import authentication.entity.User;
import authentication.service.UserService;

@Controller
@RequestMapping
public class MainController {

private final UserService userService;

@Autowired
public MainController(UserService userService) {
this.userService = userService;
}

@GetMapping(path = "/users")
public String usersPage(Model model) {
model.addAttribute("user", new User());
return "user";
    
}

@PostMapping(path = "/users")
public String usersShow(@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {
userService.addUser(user);
System.out.println(userService.findAll());
return "redirect:/user";
}

}
```